# How to fix my custom cursor on the footer?

Tags: css, cursor, mouse-cursor

For a portfolio, Ive used a custom cursor, but at the bottom of the page, there seems to be a strip of about 35px where the cursor on link revert to the default cursor, witch is a problem because ive set up a footer there. I suspect it's because of the way mozilla and other browsers display the name of the link. Is there a way around that?
My site is hosted on scardescalzi.com , if the footer is higher there's no problem so it really is about the end of the page

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is than your body does not fit the total height of the browser.

You shoud try setting the body `height: 100vh`, this will make you body container to be the 100% of the viewport.